# How does haskell determine the order of type variables in implicit foralls?

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

So I just recently learned about and started using `TypeApplications`, and was wondering how we can generally know what type variables we're assigning. [The documentation on `TypeApplications` I found](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/TypeApplication) mentions:

> What order is used to instantiate the type variables?
>
> Left-to-right order of the type variables appearing in the foralls. This is the most logical order that occurs when the instantiation is done at the type-variable level. Nested foralls work slightly differently, but at a single forall location with multiple variables, left-to-right order takes place. (See below for nested foralls).

However I haven't found mention of how order of type variables in implicit foralls is determined. I tried looking at different examples with `-fprint-explicit-foralls` to see if there was a simple pattern, but I'm getting different results in different versions of ghci. :/

In ghci version 8.0.2, I get:

```
> :t (,,)
(,,) :: forall {c} {b} {a}. a -> b -> c -> (a, b, c)
```

while in ghci version 8.4.3, I get:

```
> :t (,,)
(,,) :: forall {a} {b} {c}. a -> b -> c -> (a, b, c)
```

Then again, maybe that's simply a bug in how foralls were being printed in 8.0.2, because otherwise type applications seem to be done right-to-left with the variables of forall, contrary to what the documentation says:

```
> :t (,,) @Bool
(,,) @Bool :: forall {c} {b}. Bool -> b -> c -> (Bool, b, c)
```

So are type variables put in implicit foralls always in the order they appear first left-to-right in the type body (including the constraints)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

TL;DR: Type variable order is determined by first left-to-right encounter.  When in doubt, use `:type +v`.

#### Don't use `:type`

Using `:type` is misleading here. `:type` infers the type of a whole expression. So when you write `:t (,)`, the type checker looks at

```
(,) :: forall a b. a -> b -> (a, b)
```

and instantiates all the forall’s with fresh type variables

```
(,) :: a1 -> b1 -> (a1, b1)
```

which is necessary if you would apply `(,)`. Alas, you don’t, so type inference is almost done, and it generalizes over all free variables, and you get, for example,

```
(,) :: forall {b} {a}. a -> b -> (a, b)
```

This step makes no guarantees over the order of the free variable, and the compiler is free to change.

Also note that it writes `forall {a}` instead of `forall a`, which means that you can’t use visible type application here.

#### Use `:type +v`

But of course you can use `(,) @Bool` – but here the type-checker treats the first expression differently and does not do this instantiation/generalization step.

And you can get this behaviour in GHCi as well – [pass `+v` to `:type`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#ghci-cmd-:type%20+v):

```
:type +v (,)
(,) :: forall a b. a -> b -> (a, b)
:type +v (,) @Bool
(,) @Bool :: forall b. Bool -> b -> (Bool, b)
```

Look, no `{…}` around type variables!

#### Where does this order come from?

The [the GHC user's guide section on visible type application](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#visible-type-application)  states:

> If an identifier’s type signature does not include an explicit forall, the type variable arguments appear in the left-to-right order in which the variables appear in the type. So, foo :: Monad m => a b -> m (a c) will have its type variables ordered as m, a, b, c.

That this only applies to things that have an explicit type signature. There is no guaranteed order to variables in inferred types, but you also can't use expressions with inferred types with `VisibleTypeApplication`.

Comment: Seems `:type +v` is unavailable in 8.0.2; I get a "parse error on input ‘+’". This also doesn't really answer the question. Is that because the way the order of type variables is determined is subject to change? If it is, then I guess I could always check in ghci before using a value, but I was wondering if I could determine how to apply type values from only looking at documentation.

Comment: You can only use type applications on things that have a type signature, and there the order is determined by [the order they appear lexically in the type signature](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#visible-type-application).

If GHC has to infer the type (no type annocation around), then there is no guaranteed order – but you also cannot use such an expression with visible type application.

Comment: I provided an edit that tries to incorporate your comment as part of the answer.